# Spring Boot 2 WebClient response convert JSON to HashMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, webclient, reactive

I would like to get a response from WebClient and convert it to just a Map without creating any Class for the response. Is it possible? So I would like something like this below. The code below is not a valid code, it is just an idea of what I want.

```
public Map<String, String> someFunction() {
    return webClient.post()
            .uri("/some/path")               
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(HashMap.class)
            .block();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in saving a LOC, you may want to look at a core Spring Framework class: `ParameterizedTypeReference<T>`, found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html).

```java
public Map<String, String> someFunction() {
    return webClient.post()
            .uri("/some/path")               
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String,String>>(){})
            .block();
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I would first try getting the response object into a String and also make sure I am accepting JSON type in return. Once I get the respone into a String, you can try using fasterxml's jackson databind library which can convert a JSON string into Hashmap.

For example

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{\"name\":\"abc\", \"age\":25}";

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// convert JSON string to Map
map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});

System.out.println(map);
```

Here is the databind library and core library java docs link

[jackson-databind](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/)

[jackson-core](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.9/)

Comment: Thanks. This idea may work but it is more complex than creating a class :) My idea was to find the way to create a Map just out of the WebClient. I need just one value from the whole JSON response and creating a Class to get that looks like not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
public Map<String, String> someFunction() {
    return webClient.post()
            .uri("/some/path")               
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(TypedMap.class)
            .block();
}

private static class TypedMap extends HashMap<String, String>{}
```